# Is this a correct pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to match a pattern and replace it. However, the program is not quitting, so I am suspecting that the regex is wrong so it is not detecting and replacing the correct pattern. This is the pattern I am trying to replace:

```
Q_n(0;\al,\be,N)
```

And below is my code which is supposed to detect it using regex and replace it with:

```
\HahnQ{n}@{0}{\al}{\be}{N}
```

Thanks!

```
while(line.contains("Q_n")){
    line.replaceAll("Q_n\\(([^;]+?);([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^\\)]+?)\\)", "\\HahnQ{n}@{$1}{$2}{$3}{$4}");
}
```

Comment: "the program is not quitting" ?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that your problem is that you forgot that Strings are immutable so method like `replaceAll` doesn't change original string it was invoked on, but creates another string.

Also you are using `while`, but `replaceAll` will replace all occurrences of your 
pattern so `if` should be enough.

Another thing: if `"\\H"` should represent literal `\H` then you need to write it as `"\\\\H"` because `\` is also special character in replacement, so if you want to create literal `\` it needs to be replaced with another `\\` which needs to be written as `"\\\\"` (just like in regex)`.

```
if(line.contains("Q_n")){
    line = line.replaceAll("Q_n\\(([^;]+?);([^,]+?),([^,]+?),([^\\)]+?)\\)", "\\\\HahnQ{n}@{$1}{$2}{$3}{$4}");
}
```

BTW you don't need to make your quantifiers reluctant `([^;]+?);` because `[^;]` can't never match `;`, so is the same as `([^;]+);` (same goes to `([^,]+?),`).

Also you don't have to escape `)` inside character class `[]`

```
([^\\)]+?)\\)
   ^^     ^^
   |       +-- correct, `)` is outside of any character class `[...]`
   +---------- redundant, character class doesn't consider `)` as metacharacter
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is that the changes are not being saved to the line variable, try replacing:

```
line.replaceAll("...", "...");
```

with

```
line = line.replaceAll("...", "...");
```

Currently, your line variable will always contain `"Q_n"`, which is why you are in an infinite loop.

Comment: "*Therefore, you are in an infinite loop*" I though so too but OP is removing `Q_n\\...` by replacing it with `\\HahnQ{n}...` so infinite loop will exist only if there is `"Q_n"` which will never be matched with regex.

Comment: I was not specific. I was referring to version with `line = line.replaceAll(..)` so in that case `while` should be changed to `if`. Anyway you are right, without `line = ` part this will end up in infinite loop if condition in `while` will be fulfilled once.

Comment: @Pshemo sorry if I was not clear. I was describing what was happening while executing his current code.